# Element link not found in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I am executing a simple recorded script in Selenium , in which i just search a page in Google and then click it , but when Run that recorded script it is giving me the "Error [error] Element link not found".

And following is the Script which i am running,any help would be very useful.

New Test

New Test


    open
    /
    


    type
    q
    Bill Gates


    click
    link=Bill Gates: Chairman
    


    click
    link=Bill Gates: Chairman

Answer (score 8):

I got the same error message while going through the tutorials online.  I found out that the scripts were running too fast for FF to load the links. If you slow down the playback by moving the green button on the Fast-Slow bar to somewhere in the middle the scripts run without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I know the answer. It might be bcz of any javascript error(you can see that on the status bar at the 
Right corner(IE)) or that link element might not be placed correctly in the box(box model).
Here you can use
Selenium.focus("link=text") 
 :selenium.keyPressNative("10") . It presses the enter key.but while selenium is executing this statement
Do not change the focus from your AUT (don't touch the mouse).
In IDE ,just paste the  above statement on click().

Comment: I thanks , i get the solution it was due to the fact that it looks for the Google search results prior to i press the <search> button , i think there needs to add a statement to press the <search> button/

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think you have to slow the speed down. You know the problem is caused by clicking on the link before it is available, so you could add an extra command `waitForVisible` (e.g. `link=Bill Gates: Chairman`) before the `clickAndWait` command.

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you are using Google instant as there is no "click search button" command, the link is probably not preset because selenium is not waiting for Google instant to respond or the javascript to render the link. If you manually add in a click command to search it should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is almost the same as Cuongs. Though I change the speed by using a command and change it back afterwards.

Before you click the link, you can set the speed to slow:
Command: setSpeed
Target: 3000

You can change the speed afterwards again to ~1000

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem. I did two things which fixed the problem. I changed the speed in Selenium IDE from fast to slow (located at top left of IDE), and I minimized the IDE after hitting play button. I guess for people using only one monitor, minimizing Selenium IDE would help the test find the thing it is looking for; for ppl with two screens, opening Selenium IDE in one screen, and opening browser in another screen would be best.

Info: Installing this plug-in (Selenium IDE: Flow Control) fixed lots of unexpected errors for me while playing with Selenium IDE:-
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flow-control/?src=dp-dl-othersby