# error Element link='tabname' not found in selenium IE

Tags: selenium-ide

I am new to Selenium , while using an selenium IE I am getting an error,

`"[error] Element link='tabname' not found"` .

It's a click event, tried `clickAndWait` event but also getting the same error.

Comment: [Close to yours issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349245/element-link-not-found-in-selenium)

Comment: Please provide HTML of the webpage

Answer (score -1):

The xpath you specified for the 'tab'might not be correct.

Comment: This is NOT an answer rather a guessing which should be placed in comment.